# Disable Options Available in the Update Maven Project Window in RAD

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, ibm-rad

I want to disable the **Update Project Configuration From Pom.xml**
and **Refresh Workspace Resources from Local File System** options so
that whenever I have to **Clean** the Maven Projects, I won't have to
select these options by mistake.
Can Anybody please help me.

[image]

Comment: Similar problem for me, instead I want to make these options to be _activated_ by default :) Have you found a solution or where to configure?

Comment: Not Yet, I even posted the same question in the IBM but no answers yet  https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/356850/disable-options-available-in-the-update-maven-proj.html

Comment: @greencheese Any news with this topic? Because I'm interested in disabling these checkboxes as well.

Answer (score 0):

With current version (1.3.0-SNAPSHOT), this seems not to be configurable. See the source code: https://github.com/achingbrain/m2e-core/blob/master/org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/ui/internal/dialogs/UpdateMavenProjectsDialog.java

```
btnUpdateProjectConfiguration = new Button(optionsComposite, SWT.CHECK);
btnUpdateProjectConfiguration.setSelection(true);
btnUpdateProjectConfiguration.setText(Messages.UpdateMavenProjectDialog_btnUpdateProjectConfiguration_text);
//
btnCleanProjects = new Button(optionsComposite, SWT.CHECK);
btnCleanProjects.setSelection(true);
btnCleanProjects.setText(Messages.UpdateMavenProjectDialog_btnCleanProjects_text);
```

So we have to push your request on developers side :)

Comment: I didn't try it myself, since it is not that urgent for me :)

Comment: You can find the code over here now

https://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/tree/org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/ui/internal/dialogs/UpdateMavenProjectsDialog.java

and it still doesn't allow customisation